# Lambda with generic

Tags: c#, generics

```
IDictionary<string, string> map = str.Split('|')
                                     .ToDictionary(s => s.Split('@')[0], s => s.Split('@')[1]);
```

The above statement works. But I would like to change it to generic for `IDictionary`

```
public class CSVMap <TKey, TValue>
{
    public IDictionary<TKey, TValue>  func (string str)
    {
        IDictionary<TKey, TValue> map =  str.Split('|').ToDictionary (ConvertValue<TKey>(s => s.Split('@')[0]), ConvertValue<TValue>(s => s.Split('@')[1]));

    }
    public static T ConvertValue<T>(string value)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
```

and `ConvertValue` to cast the split strings to the type of `TKey` and `TValue`.

But I got these errors for the `ConvertValue` portions:

> error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
>   error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

I am not sure what the errors mean or how to fix such a problem.

Comment: The correct term is "generics", not "templates". Templates is what C++ has.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: .. *change it to **template** for IDictionary* <= you missed one ..

Answer (score 5):

You are passing a lambda expression to the ConvertValue function rather than the value.  Not sure if this does what you expect, but this is the correct syntax atleast.

```
IDictionary<TKey, TValue> map =  str.Split('|').ToDictionary (s=>ConvertValue<TKey>(s.Split('@')[0]), s=>ConvertValue<TValue>(s.Split('@')[1]));
```